# Link Error while compiling vc++ project

Tags: visual-c++

I am getting the following error.
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __localtime64_s
On searching on the internet i found that there is a library WINMM.LIB which is needed to be included. So i added this library in the project options.
But,it still does not help.
Can somebody help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_s` suffix indicates that its actually probably one of the "safe" apis added to Visual Studio 2005 or 2008. There are two leading `_'s` - the first indicates the function decoration - an `extern "C"` function using the `__cdecl` calling convention. The next `'_'` inidcates that the functions is an OEM (Microsoft in this case) extension to the c-runtime library.

Specifically it seems to be a worker function invoked from 'Program Files\Visual Studio\VS\include\time.inl' when the safe 'localtime' function is called.

So, at a guess I would say that you are not linking in the c-runtime libraries correctly into your application. Are you using any options like "exclude default libraries" or are excluding any specific libraries in your projects settings?

Comment: where to check if the default libraries are excluded?

Comment: right click on the project in the solution explorer, choose properties, and go to the linker settings. Under Configuration Properties->Linker->Input are two settings: Ignore All Default Libraries and Ignore Specific Library that may be causing problems.